# Symfony2 - fos create super admin custom field required

Tags: deployment, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I am deploying a SF2.1 project into production.
I have customized the user model so that certain fields are required.
So when I try to create my super admin

```
$ php app/console fos:user:create admin my@mail.com my_pass --super-admin
```

I'm getting

> [PDOException]
>   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'my_required_field' cannot be null

What is the clean way to manage that ?
I Imagine not manually inserting the user into the table...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should override FOSUserBundle `execute()` method in [/Command/CreateUserCommand.php](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Command/CreateUserCommand.php) and `create()` method in [/Util/UserManipulator.php](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Util/UserManipulator.php) files. By doing that you should be able to add any additional fields to your User entity from the command line.

Comment: I thought there were a way to do it without having to modify files. Ok thanks.

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY you should not modify files, but better extend stuff in your own bundle, in order to keep dependencies consistent - otherwise deploy will be a mess!

Comment: Take a look in the FOSUserBundle documentation. The "Overriding Controllers" page can give you a clue on how to extend functionality in your own bundle without modifying FOSUserBundle files. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You can either override the CLI command in order to provide the required field, or just provide a default value in class constructor in case it is a scalar.